# Testing Constructors with JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have a constructor that creates objects containing an integer and a string. I created a test that creates an object using the constrcutor and then checks that the object is not null:

```
@Test
public void testMainConstructorCorrectArg()
{
    customReview = new WorkshopReview(1, "More boring than G51FSE");
    assertNotNull(customReview);
}
```

I also feel like I should be checking the values of the int and string using assertEquals in combination with the "get" functions for the int and string but that feels counter intuitive because I haven't yet written tests for the "get" functions.

Should I be testing the values contained in the objects in the test for the constructor or the tests for the get functions or both?

Comment: This isn't a useful test - calling `new ...` will never return `null`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ok so what should I do to test that a constructor works properly? Should I be testing the values of the object that is created? If so is it ok to use "get" functions that haven't been tested yet?

Comment: Define "works properly" - what behaviour are you expecting your constructor to have?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth the constructor should create an object which contains a score (integer) and review (string). The specification stated that the score should be between 0-5 inclusive and that the review should be over some reasonable minimum number of characters. It does not state what the constructor should do if the score is not between 0-5 so I just created a test which expects an IllegalArgumentException when 7 or -3 are passed which fails as it should because the constructor doesn't throw one.

Comment: Test whatever you can. Yes, that should include using the getters to compare the values.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Ok so if I use the getters in the constructor test do I use that as the test for the getters too because otherwise I would end up writing 2 tests that did the same thing, create an object using constructer then use getter to check value.

Comment: Testing typical getters for themselves is a waste of time most of the time. I wouldn't write specific tests for them (as long as they are really just simple `return x;` getters), but instead use them in other tests. As soon as the getters start containing logic, then I would test them for themselves.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Ok thank you :)